# Roblox studio text for starter gui is not changing

Tags: roblox-studio

The problem is that i cant make it visible or change text i cant edit any properties of it but it looks like i can?

Im making a horror game and i made a cutscene which it starts of changing text of a screengui in startgui then after cutscene is done the phone rings and when you click it its suppose to change text but its not doing it. All the other stuff is working like wait() and Destroy() so please help me

This is my script:

```
local textlabel = game.StarterGui.Diolog.TextLabel

function onClicked(playerWhoClicked)
    textlabel.Visible = true
    script.Parent.Parent.Screen:Destroy()
ex
end

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onClicked)
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm assuming this is in a server script, so</strike> firstly you should get rid of `local textlabel = game.StarterGui.Diolog.TextLabel` because <strike>(1): you have not provided the server with which player you are trying to affect at this point, and (2):</strike> by default, players copy the contents of StarterGui only when they join the game and respawn; so changes to StarterGui after that has happened will not affect the player.

It's not clear what you're trying to do since you provided little detail and no output, but as far as I can tell, my suggestion still works as a localscript. I added a check as well to make sure that the label is there.

Besides that, there are quite a few other basic syntax issues that suggest that  you may benefit from reading the first few chapters of Lua manual. Try this, though.

```lua
local function onClicked(playerWhoClicked)
    local textlabel = playerWhoClicked.PlayerGui.Diolog.TextLabel
    if (textlabel) then
        textlabel.Visible = true
        script.Parent.Parent.Screen:Destroy()
    end
end

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(onClicked)
```

[StarterGui Documentation](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/StarterGui)

Comment: its not in a server script the script is inside the phone model in workspace and the script makes startergui text change but its not doing that

Comment: Yes, but as I said, changes to `StarterGui` will not reflect to players until they respawn*. You need to instead change the player's `PlayerGui`. I have edited my post.

*(if you have the ResetOnSpawn property turned on).